# Two squares are chosen without replacement from the $64$ squares of a chessboard. What's the probability that we chose two on the same row?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

All the choices are equally likely.

What is the probability that we chose a square on the same row? The number of ways we can choose two squares in general is $64 \choose 2$ and the number of ways we can choose two squares such that they're on the same row is $8 \choose 2$, so the probability would be $8\choose 2$ $/$ $64 \choose 2$. Same goes for the probability of choosing two squares in the same column. Is this correct?

Also, what's the probability of choosing two black squares? For this I'm not sure. I want to say $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  $$32 \choose 2$ $/$ $64\choose 2$ but I think this would be ignoring the "no replacement" part of the question...

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of which square you pick first, there are $63$ equally likely choices for the second square, of which $7$ are in the same row as the first, so the probability you want is $7/63 = 1/9$.

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but the number of ways in which we choose two squares such that they are both in the **first** row is $\binom{8}{2}$.  You neglected to account for the possibility that we chose from a row different than the first.

Begin by picking *which* row we are choosing from.  Then pick which squares *within that row* they were.

Your answer for choosing black squares is correct.  It is not ignoring the "no replacement" part.  Rather, it is precisely how you *handle* the no replacement part.  If we were choosing with replacement, that would have been $64^2$ for the denominator instead of $\binom{64}{2}$

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense! So it would be $8*$$8 \choose 2$ possible ways to pick two squares in the same row or column. And got it, I think I was overthinking the second part so it's good to know that I was fine. Thank you for all the help!